# How to fill the drop down list dynamically in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

My target is to dynamically fill a drop-down list.  I have the password of 10 characters and I need to fill any combination of three words. I'm able to fill it use the message shown like `Please fill 2,3 and 5 character`, but this is depended on the String.

How should I do this thing dynamically in selenium so that the unfilled box are automatically identified and gives me the place where to fill.

I have implemented this code using String

```
int identifingPlacesToField =0;
    String masterPassword ="jeffhrdyrt";
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(driver.findElement(By.id("pass_Login_form")).findElement(By.tagName("div")).getText().toString());
        while(m.find()) 
        {
            identifingPlacesToField++;
            Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("sel"+identifingPlacesToField)));
            select.selectByValue(String.valueOf(masterPassword.charAt(Integer.parseInt(m.group(0))-1)));
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("passBtnSubmit")).click(); 
        TestingHLTestCases.checkingPortfolioPage();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In this Matcher is getting what are the digits and I am filling accordingly. But Now I want a similar thing without using string.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue u have to do java coding.

Identify place to fill and use if else loop like

```
if(fieldfirst == 1)
{
Enter first word
}
else if(fieldfirst == 2)
{
Enter second word
}
```

continue this till u need it